# Fixed effects with ggeffect()

Tags: r

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience using `ggeffect()` with lots of fixed effects. Although my independent variable is strongly related to my dependent variable, I get these massive confidence intervals when I add in state fixed effects.

A toy example:

```
set.seed(200)

indvar <- runif(500, min = 0, max = .5)
state <- as.factor(rep(c(1:50), 10))
statev <- as.integer(state) * runif(500, 0, 0.02)
depvar <- round(indvar + statev)

data <- data.frame(indvar, state, depvar)

m1 <- glm(depvar ~ indvar, data = data, family = "binomial")

margin <- ggeffect(m1, "indvar")

plot(margin)
```

[image: Plot with expected confidence intervals]

This gives me nice clean confidence intervals around the independent variable.
However, as soon as I add in the state fixed effects, the confidence interval stretches essentially from 0 to 1, even though there remains a super strong relationship.

```
m2 <- glm(depvar ~ indvar + state, data = data, family = "binomial")

margin <- ggeffect(m2, "indvar")

plot(margin)
```

[image: Plot with super wide confidence intervals]

Thoughts much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have a [complete separation](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/) problem (see also [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression)), which as shown in the @Ewen's answer makes the Wald standard errors of the parameters (and hence the Wald confidence intervals on the predictions) ridiculously large. (To answer one of your questions in the comments, complete separation only occurs in GLMs, not linear models.)

In principle you could deal with this using your current model by computing confidence intervals on the predictions based on bootstrapping or based on computing likelihood profiles of the predictions. These are both a little tricky (bootstrapping would require a stratified bootstrap where you resampled each state's responses with replacement; profile confidence intervals on predicted values would require implemented a constrained nonlinear optimization method ...).

A (much) simpler solution, if you're willing to change your model slightly, is to use a *penalized* GLM (Firth), e.g. as implemented in the [brglm2 package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=brglm2):

```
library(brglm2)
m2B <- update(m2, method=brglmFit)
plot(ggeffect(m2B,"indvar"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting.

The way you have set up your data and model, the model does not converge (estimates on states are very imprecise).

So when you generate marginal predicted probabilities for your explanatory variable holding one state constant (state 1 by default), you naturally get lots of variation.

```
> summary(m2)

Call:
glm(formula = depvar ~ indvar + state, family = "binomial", data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.53196  -0.53627  -0.00006   0.54430   2.20165  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -21.8541  1854.7192  -0.012    0.991    
indvar        10.7116     1.1952   8.962   <2e-16 ***
state2        -0.1773  2577.7112   0.000    1.000    
state3         0.2353  2534.9784   0.000    1.000    
state4         0.5125  2569.5228   0.000    1.000
.
.
.
```

You don't mention any background, but you may wish to consider state as a random effect (random intercept model).

```
library(lme4)
m2 <- glmer(depvar ~ indvar + (1 | state), data = data, family = "binomial")
```

**Edit**

You have States with either no zeros or ones, so the model can't converge. I guess that's why people say always plot your data first!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Because I need to do some interpretive work on the coefficients for the individual state elsewhere, I unfortunately need to keep the state fixed effects (which, in my actual data, are not random as they are in this toy example). A more general question - why do the wide confidence intervals not occur when using ggpredict(), or in ggeffect() when the model is specified using lm() (which is incorrect in this case as I've got a binary dv)?

Comment: You can use `ranef()` to interpret the random effects. And "random" does not mean you have a random variable, but a variable with a random selection of categories from a larger sample of (theoretically possible) categories. Whereas fixed effects usually do not change when you take a different sample (like gender or education, which levels are usually "fixed"). Thus I would also suggest you try a mixed model.

Comment: Edit above to help you see why the model doesn't converge with States as fixed effects using your toy data. It wouldn't necessarily be case with your real data, but always plot it. E