# Logistic regression model in R to identify inventory items that should require safety stock returning warnings

Tags: r, warnings, logistic-regression, training-data

I've been working on building a logistic regression model in R with the goal of using it to identify whether or not any given item dataset of new inventory items should require safety stock.

When attempting to run this model, I receive warning messages:
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

I'm attempting to train the model on a dataset of current inventory items with variables including: Lead Time (in days), unit cost (in dollars), and daily usage (quantity/day). Using whether or not the item needs safety stock as the dependent variable in the model, with values of 1 being yes and 0 being no.

Model code for reference:
SafetyStock_model <- glm(formula = SafetyStock ~ UnitCost + LeadTime + DailyUsage,
family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = SafetyStock_Train)

This code returns the warning messages listed above

I know this can happen if you're seeing perfect separation, but I don't think this should be happening with the data I'm using. Any ideas on why this might be happening, or how I could address it? All input is appreciated

Thank you!

Edit: Sample of data and summary of model in current state included.

```
structure(list(PartNumber = c("72150", "66K4A3SN-SF", "AN320-4", "67L20423", "72245", "60N29740-CT", "LW-16107", "65990", "LW-349290-1-70", "31M22993"), UnitCost = c(93.45, 752.584, 0.4984, 142.044, 784.24486, 0.16198, 101.12536, 33.642, 610.2285, 784.24486), DailyUsage =c(0.0145833333333333, 1.10833333333333, 0.0229166666666667,0.00416666666666667, 0.06875, 0.00833333333333333,0.0104166666666667, 0.00208333333333333, 0.0166666666666667, 0.0520833333333333), LeadTime = c(35, 180, 40, 30, 130,365, 90, 40, 40, 130), SafetyStock = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names =c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


Call:
glm(formula = SafetyStock ~ UnitCost + LeadTime + DailyUsage, 
family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = SafetyStock_Train)

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error      z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -2.677e+02  3.951e+02  -0.678    0.498
UnitCost     1.284e-03  1.011e-02   0.127    0.899
LeadTime     1.296e-01  3.420e-01   0.379    0.705
DailyUsage   5.122e+03  7.660e+03   0.669    0.504

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 1.1914e+03  on 1026  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 7.6262e-03  on 1023  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8.0076

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

Comment: If you could share a sample of your data using `dput(0` it would be much easier? Can you at least what types of variables these are?

Comment: @nrennie, I've uploaded an image to show data used

Comment: Please don't share data as images (it doesn't help us in being able to run your code) - can you run e.g. `dput(head(SafetyStock_Train, 10))` and paste the contents into a code block instead?

Comment: Could you please also post the output of the `summary()` of your model (as text, not an image)?

Comment: By the way, these are warnings and not errors (if they had been errors you wouldn't have gotten any results at all) - it's a useful distinction ...

Comment: @nrennie sample of data has been included

Comment: @BenBolker Summary of model in current state has been included

Comment: Thank you all for your patience. I'm not super experienced with using this site!

Comment: The huge parameter estimate for `DailyUsage` and the even larger SE are **strong** indicators of complete separation. Have you looked around at the methods for diagnosing and addressing complete separation, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019055/190277 , https://bbolker.github.io/stat4c03/notes/separation.pdf ?